# XHR - Bypass Expired SSL Cert

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I try to make a vanilla XHR request to a domain with an expired SSL certificate. I get the following response:

```
Error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
    at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1349:32)
    at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:962:10)
    at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:463:15)
    at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
    at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:219:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:209:5)
    at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
    at write (_stream_readable.js:573:24)
```

That makes sense. Its the same when you browse to a site with an invalid certificate. However, on a browser, you can say:

#### I don't care, continue!

How does one do this with an XHR request?

I have spent a considerable amount of time looking on the internet for a solution to this, and the only responses I can seem to find are people avoiding answering by stating that it is insecure and one shouldn't.

- I know the site I am connecting should have an updated cert. It isn't. Heartbreaking as it is to all perfectionists, I still need to connect.
- Yes, I am sure it is secure.
- I'll have a word with those who haven't updated the cert. Nevertheless, it is not fixed and I need to connect.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: Open the domain an another window and click the **I don't care, continue** button then try your XHR again.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am making the request from Node.js, so I can't do that. I didn't include that part in my question as its not really relevant and will scare away 50+% of the people who might have an answer to this question.

Comment: You might want to tag the question as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you could do is proxy your request through a `curl` or `wget` spawned through a child process. You'd use either the `--insecure` or `--no-check-certificate` options to avoid erroring on the expired cert. There are npm modules to assist using [curl](https://github.com/jiangmiao/node-curl) or [wget](https://github.com/wuchengwei/node-wget) through node.

Though I think once you realize how much of an ugly, ugly hack this is, you'll come up with enough motivation to get the admin of the site to update their cert.

Comment: Oh, let me tell you... nice hat btw :)

Comment: Is curl able to send cookies and send HTTP verbs? Another beautiful problem is that just before this request I have to manually inject authentication cookies into my xhr request. *cought* pacaps *cough*

Comment: Yes, curl is able to.